# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am receiving the following error when create the stored procedure:

```
Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure autotramenlunallocated, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 9]
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

Below is the Stored Procedure

```
USE [LMGCRM]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[assgnzambtautoleadsforRoundtest]    Script Date: 2019/09/30 11:16:43 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[autotramenlunallocated]
AS
BEGIN
Insert into unactionedautotraders 
Select * from autotr_2menl p
        left  join customers C
        ON C.code=p.Ref
where c.contacted IS NULL and p.DaySS >='1'
END
GO
```

Comment: This query returns more columns: Select * from autotr_2menl p left join customers C ON C.code=p.Ref where c.contacted IS NULL and p.DaySS >='1' Then this table has 'unactionedautotraders'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why you should always declare your columns both in your `INSERT` and `SELECT`.

Change both of them to declare all the columns you are inserting and selecting, so your statement looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.unactionedautotraders (code, Ref, contacted, DaySS)
SELECT C.code, P.Ref, C.contacted, P.DaySS
FROM dbo.autotr_2menl P
     LEFT JOIN Customers C ON P.Ref = C.Code
WHERE C.contacted IS NULL
  AND P.DaySS >= 1; --Not sure why this was a varchar?
```

It's also very strongly advised to never use `*` in a persisted object. When you use `SELECT *` in a `VIEW` SQL Server will "convert" that to the current list of columns in the object at that point, not when the `VIEW` is run. Therefore if you add more columns to the table, they will **not** be included. Example:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            MyColumn varchar(10));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID,
                           MyColumn)
VALUES(1,'Test')
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.YourView AS

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.YourTable

GO

SELECT * --Returns both columns
FROM dbo.YourView;
GO

--Add a new column
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD MyDate date;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID,
                           MyColumn,
                           MyDate)
VALUES(2,'Test',GETDATE());
GO

SELECT * --Returns only ID and MyColumn, not MyDate
FROM dbo.YourView;
GO
--This will error
SELECT ID,
       MyColumn,
       MyDate
FROM dbo.YourView;
```

This behaviour is not replicated with an SP.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.YourProc @ID int
AS BEGIN

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ID = @ID
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.YourProc @ID = 2; --Returns 3 columns
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD MyInteger int;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID,
                           MyColumn,
                           MyDate,
                           MyInteger)
VALUES(3,'Test',GETDATE(),12);
GO
EXEC dbo.YourProc @ID = 3; --Returns 4 columns
```

This does not change my recommendation. In fact, I stress it more, as *if* you were to be inserting data into another table (like you are here) altering the either the source or destination tables will break your SP (maybe that's what happened here):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int,
                          MyColumn varchar(10),
                          MyDate date,
                          MyInteger int);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.InsertProc @ID int
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 3; --works

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyTime time(0);
GO
EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 1; --fails;
GO
--Undo and change your table instead
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP COLUMN MyTime;
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD MyDecimal decimal (10,2);
GO

EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 2; --fails;
GO
SELECT * --Just 1 row
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

As you can see, however, if we declare our columns properly (both in the `INSERT` and `SELECT`) then this problem does not occur:

```
--Change proc to have column names
ALTER PROC dbo.InsertProc @ID int
AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID,MyColumn)
    SELECT ID, MyColumn
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
GO

EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 2; --works;
GO
--Add a column to MyTable
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD MyTime time(0);
GO

EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 1; --still works;
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD MyBinary varbinary(10);
GO
EXEC dbo.InsertProc @ID = 4; --still works, inserts no data as no ID 4
GO

SELECT * --3 rows (some have NULLs)
FROM dbo.MyTable; 


GO
--Clean up
DROP PROC dbo.InsertProc;
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
DROP PROC dbo.YourProc;
DROP VIEW dbo.YourView;
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

*No DB Fiddle, as unfortunately they don't replicate the true behaviour.*

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[autotramenlunallocated]
AS
BEGIN
Insert into unactionedautotraders(column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )---------Select Column that u want to insert into that 
Select p.column1,p.column2,C.someInt,C.someVarChar from autotr_2menl p    ---------Select Same No. of column and data type as above Line...
        left  join customers C
        ON C.code=p.Ref
where c.contacted IS NULL and p.DaySS >='1'
END
```

**Note:-** INSERT INTO SELECT requires that data types in source and target tables match.